# T-SQL querying XML column with XPath very slow - how to improve, or alternatives?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

I have a table that contains a XML data type column. Right now the approach is to use XPath to query values that are within the XML. Unfortunately this method is turning out to be extremely slow.

The table has about 500,000 rows. It is actually a staging table that receives new data every day, so applying XML indexing on the column is not practical - the daily INSERT operation then takes hours to complete. Without indexing, it finishes in about a minute.

Are there any alternatives to query this XML data that would be much faster?

Comment: If you need some kind of persistent index, maybe XML is not your format...

Comment: An index isn't needed - XML indexes seemed to be a common solution I found, so I tried it, but it doesn't seem practical for my situation. Unfortunately I don't have much choice on the XML format.

Comment: Is it possible to modify the application/whatever that is supplying new data? Because XML support in MSSQL was a terrible terrible mistake and you really should preprocess such data outside.

Answer (score 7):

How many of the items inside the XML do you need to query on a regular basis?? Just a few??

The solution we've chosen facing the same issues is this:

- create a stored function that takes an `XML` parameter as its input
- in that function, extract the information you need from the XML using XQuery/XPath
- create a **computed persisted column** on your table that references that function

In that way, we're pulling out the three, four most frequently used items of information (often just an INT, in our case) and making them available as columns on the base table. Since they're persisted, they won't be recalculated on every access - only if the XML contents changes; and also since they're persisted, you can put a regular nonclustered index on them, if need be.

Example:

we have a function that extracts a BIT from the XML telling us whether or not a given contract has a VPN connection or not:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetVPNFlag(@Data XML)
RETURNS BIT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS BEGIN
  DECLARE @VPNFlag BIT

  SELECT  
    @VPNFlag = ISNULL(@Data.value('(EntryIP/VPNOption)[1]', 'bit'), 0)

  RETURN @VPNFlag
END
```

Given an XML, this will pick out the VPN flag and return it. Next, we created a computed persisted column on our base table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ContractData
  ADD IsVPN AS dbo.GetVPNFlag(XmlData) PERSISTED
```

Here, we're passing in the `XmlData` contents from the `ContractData` table, into the function. We're getting back a BIT, which is stored as `IsVPN` column on the `ContractData` table.

We can now easily get all contracts with VPN like this:

```
SELECT (list of fields) 
FROM dbo.ContractData
WHERE IsVPN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same situation and amount of data and after tuning ended up in having a insert & update trigger inserting data in "datawarehouse tables". This gives a slower insert but workable for our users.